# Making echo "foo" | sudo tee -a idempotent

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tee

I am using the following shell command to append a string to a file:

```
echo "latest stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/my-app.conf > /dev/null
```

However this is not idempotent, i.e. if the string already exists in `/etc/my-app.conf` it is appended multiple times each time the command is invoked. Is it possible to only append if it doesn't exist in a clever one-liner?

Comment: *grumble* -- seeking a "clever one-liner" rather than seeking a *correct* solution is a fast route to subtly buggy code, particularly in bash (which is full of subtle pitfalls, workarounds to avoid which are often not terse).

Comment: ...that said -- is it only other instances of the same program you need to worry about (such that a cooperative/advisory locking approach is permissible), or do we also care about interoperability with non-cooperating writers?

Comment: Also, what scale is the length of this file? Do we want to read it into memory, or should we not be assuming that it'll fit?

Comment: This command can be invoked multiple times as part of configuration management, and currently the file `/etc/my-app.conf` has `latest stable main` on like 50 lines over and over again. That's the use-case.

Comment: If you don't care about handling concurrency correctly or independently evaluating whether each line is duplicative of existing content, this could just be `grep -e 'latest stable main' yourfile || ...`. Though one *should* care, of course. :)

Comment: Make a config directory `/etc/my-app.conf.d/` and then simply touch `/etc/my-app.conf.d/latest` . Let the fs handle it.

Answer (score 3):

#### The Short Answer: Simple, Easy And Wrong

If you don't care about correctness in corner cases (multi-line inputs, concurrent invocations, etc), the following will *sorta* do the job:

```
grep -Fxe 'latest stable main' /etc/my-app.conf || {
  sudo tee -a /etc/my-app.conf <<<"latest stable main"
}
```

For an answer that cares more about correctness than terseness, read on.

---

#### The Long Answer: Per-Line Evaluation With Locking

As an answer that doesn't try to be terse, but *does* pay some attention to correctness (including correct operation when multiple instances of the below are invoked concurrently):

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^^^- shebang present as an editor hint; this file should be sourced, not executed.

case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*|4.0.*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.1 or newer required" >&2; return 1 >/dev/null 2>&1; exit 1;; esac

appendEachNewLine() {
  local file=$1 line out_fd
  local -A existingContents=( )   # associative array, to track lines that already exist

  # dynamically assign a file descriptor on which to both lock our file and write
  exec {out_fd}>>"$file"
  flock -x -n "$out_fd" || {
    echo "ERROR: Unable to lock destination file" >&2
    exec {out_fd}>&-
    return 1
  }

  # read existing lines once, through a new file descriptor, only after holding the lock
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    existingContents[$line]=1
  done <"$file"

  # then process our stdin, appending each line if not previously seen
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if ! [[ ${existingContents[$line]} ]]; then
      printf '%s\n' "$line" >&"$out_fd"
    fi
  done

  # close the file, thus releasing the lock, when done.
  exec {out_fd}>&-
}

appendEachNewLineAsRoot() {
  sudo bash -c "$(declare -f appendEachNewLine)"'; appendEachNewLine "$@"' appendEachNewLine "$@";
}
```

As an example of how you might use this to replace your old command, after `source`ing the above script:

```
echo "latest stable main" | appendEachNewLineAsRoot /etc/my-app.conf
```

Comment: If it's an editor hint, why both with `/usr/bin/env`? The editor would probably be satisfied by `#!bash`, since the path to the interpreter isn't going to affect syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Ansible [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) module to ensure a particular line is in a file.